# What damage should I prepare for (software and hardware wise) if electricity goes off?

Tags: hardware-failure

Using a new PC and I'm concerned. In the last week electricity went off three times while I was using the PC, and I know that can potentially lead to massive damages, software or hardware wise. So how can I check if anything is damaged after that? A friend advised me to run **cmd** and type **chkdsk** to see if something's wrong with the HDD, but not sure if that is useful and reliable.

What do you recommend?

Comment: `chkdsk` is a good place to start. Strictly speaking it won't check if something's wrong with your HDD, but with the filesystem on it. (ie. your HDD may be perfectly fine, but some files may be broken because writing them was interrupted)

Answer (score 1):

If this system is important, and you have frequent power issues, you need an uninterruptible power supply, or UPS.

A UPS has a backup battery and will switch to it when your mains power goes out.  It recharges when the mains power returns.  Many UPSes also filter power.  Typically you can connect them to a PC with a serial or USB interface and install included software to monitor.  The software can safely shutdown your PC when the reserve power in the UPS gets too low.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but none of them actually answer my question. I will consider buying a UPS, even though I dont have frequent power issues, it just happens once in a while. It's the first time ever it happened 3 times in a week. 

My question actually was, what can I do in order to check if my system is all good when that happens. Software and hardware wise. Sorry if I didn't make that clear enough for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 (arguably 3) elements you need to be aware of -

1. Hardware failure.  Often when there is a power failure it is associated with a power
   surge which can damage hardware. A good UPS is a good "overall solution", but a power
   filter could help as well.
2. Software failure.  If your computer is in the middle of a disk write when the power
   goes out it could leave your system in a confused state.  This is not much of an issue
   for most newish systems as they use "journalling" filesystems which can roll back changes
   to the last known good state.  NTFS filesystems (most Windows hard drives) support this,
   but most USB keys use FAT32 which doesn't - although you can reformat a disk to NTFS if
   you know it will only ever be used in devices which support the file format.   Using
   A UPS can also give enough time to flush the system and close the PC down.
3. Other peripherals - if you are on the Internet, you may loose data if your router
   is not protected.  There are a few similar threats - if you use a UPS make sure all
   the neccessary equipment is on it.

CHKDSK is useful and reliable, but should run automatically if the system is powered down suddenly.  Some modes of chkdsk can't be run from the cmd prompt as they require the filesystem to be unmounted for repairs - in which case the system normally marks the disk as requiring repair and requires a reboot - but this is typically done through the GUI in windows.

Comment: Isn't a good UPS a bit pricey?

Comment: Its all relative.  I very good UPS (Online, decent brand) is very pricy and consumes a lot of electricity.  From what you have advised of your usage case (frequent outages), even a cheap UPS would be a good idea, as they offer some protection - and typically include monetary insurance your PC against power related issues, so they are worth looking at if money is tight.  I'd imagine a basic unit would set you back less then US$120.  A basic surge protector probably less then $35